# HTML $_POST questions

Tags: javascript, html, forms, post

I currently have a form and below the form, I have a checkbox and some radio buttons. Here is the code for the checkbox and radio buttons:

```
<li id="discountCheckbox"       class="     ">
    <label class="desc" id="title416" for="Field416">
        Discounts Available:
            </label>
    <div>
        <span>
    <input id="discountCheckbox"        name="discountCheckbox"         type="checkbox"         class="field checkbox"      value="Past Host Discount - 10%"        tabindex="12"                       />
    <label class="choice" for="Field416">Past Host Discount - 10%</label>
    </span>
        </div>
    </li>


<li id="shipping1"      class="     ">
<label class="desc" id="shippingChoice" name="shippingLabel" value="yahha" for="Field517_0">
    Shipping Options
        </label>
<div>
<input id="9281" name="9821" type="hidden" value="" />
    <span>
<input id="shipping1"       name="shipping1"        type="radio"        class="field radio"         value="cost"        tabindex="13"                        checked="checked"      onclick="setShippingSpan('$2.00');"             />
<label class="choice" for="Field517_0"      >
    $2.00 Shipping Fee</label>
    </span>
    <span>
<input id="shipping2"       name="shipping1"        type="radio"        class="field radio"         value="free"        tabindex="14"           onclick="setShippingSpan('$0.00');"                 />
<label class="choice" for="Field517_1"      >
    I will pick up the items (free shipping)</label>
    </span>
    </div>
</li>
```

On submission of my form, I have a file process.php that is run. In that file, I grab the value of the checkbox using `$_POST["discountCheckbox"]`. But, I can't figure out how to grab the value of the radio buttons (determining which one is selected). **How do I do this?**

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same ID. This is invalid HTML.

Comment: I have fixed this. Now what would I do?

Comment: Also it's good to clean up your HTML so we can help you faster...this makes it a little hard to read. Sincerest :)

Comment: Your wrote `$_POST` so that means you are using PHP? This post doesn't mention that, because a solution on catching the value would include using $_POST['shipping1'] to get the value of your radio buttons. For instance look at this article about it (http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php4p10.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give the radio buttons all the same name and then that name in your `$_POST` will have the value of the selected radio button.

Comment: I have given them the same name, so how would I do it? (see updated code)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/6RATF/ hope this helps a little. It uses jquery to get the value but it should be about the same on the other end of the form post.

Answer (score 2):

Give the radio buttons the same name but different values.  When the form is submitted look up the value which is selected by simply checking the value of that name in the $_POST array.

Comment: See the code above. I have updated it to have the same names. What would the code look like now?

Comment: $_POST['shipping1'] will now evaluate to whatever radio button is selected by the user before form submission.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your `input` elements of type `radio` should share a common `name` attribute and be distinguished by their `value` attributes.  Then, in your PHP code, you'd check the value of `$_POST[]` indexed by the name, which should contain the value of the selected radio button.

Comment: I have updated the code so that the elements of type radio have the same common name. Can you show me how to do it using $_POST?

Comment: @reising1: `$_POST["shipping1"]` should contain the value "cost" when this code posts, assuming that radio button remains checked.  Otherwise, it should contain "free" (or anything else you add to that radio button).

Comment: @reising1: Define "not working."  What value is in that array element?  What elements are in the `$_POST` array?

Comment: In my php code, I have: if($_POST["shipping1"]=="cost") {
 $response = $response . "Shipping: $$2.00<br>";

}, which doesn't work

Comment: @reising1: "Doesn't work" continues to be ambiguous.  What value is contained within `$_POST["shipping1"]` when this code executes?

Answer (score 0):

By giving all radio buttons the same name you'll get the value of the selected one in the $_POST[name] variable.

```
<input name="shipping" value="something" type="radio" />

echo $_POST['shipping']; // echoes "something"
```

Comment: I've updated the code to keep consistent names. Can you show me what the code would look like now?

Comment: They all have the name shipping1, thus the variable to use is "$_POST['shipping1']". This will hold the value of the selected radio button, in this case "cost" or "free"

Comment: in my php code I have if($_POST["shipping1"]=="cost") {
 $response = $response . "Shipping: $$2.00<br>";
 $grand += 2;
}, but it doesn't work even when I submit with the correct radio button

Comment: in fact, I print out  $response = $response . "THE VALUE IS: " . $_POST["shipping1"] . "<br>";
 which prints a blank after the colon